# Fonts not working when deploying jasperreport in PDF from web app

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I'm having some issues with the fonts when I'm deploying the reports in my web app. The fonts I want to have in my result pdfs are Arial, Calibri and Century Gothic.

I followed all the steps pointed [here](http://www.codesuggestions.com/java/jasper-reports/adding-custom-fonts-to-jasper-reports/) but couldn't get it working.

Here's what I did:

I modified the content of my **jasperreports_extension.properties** like following:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.simple.font.families=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.dejavu=net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/fonts.xml
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.arial=net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/fonts.xml
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.calibri=net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/fonts.xml
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.centurygothic=net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/fonts.xml
```

Then at **net\sf\jasperreports\fonts** I put the three folders for the fonts containing the four styles (normal, **bold**, *italic* and ***bold-italic***) for each of the fonts before mentioned.

Also, modified the **fonts.xml** at **net/sf/jasperreports/fonts** and it looks like this now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<fontFamilies>

    <fontFamily name="DejaVu Sans">
        <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf</normal>
        <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf</bold>
        <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
        <!--
        <locales>
            <locale>en_US</locale>
            <locale>de_DE</locale>
        </locales>
        -->
    </fontFamily>

    <fontFamily name="DejaVu Serif">
        <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf</normal>
        <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf</bold>
        <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>

    <fontFamily name="DejaVu Sans Mono">
        <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf</normal>
        <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf</bold>
        <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Courier New', Courier, monospace</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Courier New', Courier, monospace</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>

    <!--
        Mapping Java logical fonts, for the sake of HTML export only.
    -->

    <fontFamily name="SansSerif">
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>
    <fontFamily name="Serif">
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>
    <fontFamily name="Monospaced">
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Courier New', Courier, monospace</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Courier New', Courier, monospace</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>

    <fontFamily name="Arial">
       <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/arial/arial.ttf</normal>
       <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/arial/ArialBold.ttf</bold>
       <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/arial/ArialItalic.ttf</italic>
       <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/arial/ArialBoldItalic.ttf</boldItalic>
       <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
       <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
       <exportFonts>
           <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'Arial'</export>
           <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'Arial'</export>
       </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>

    <fontFamily name="Calibri">
       <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/calibri/calibri.ttf</normal>
       <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/calibri/calibri-bold.ttf</bold>
       <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/calibri/calibri-italic.ttf</italic>
       <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/calibri/calibri-bold-italic.ttf</boldItalic>
       <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
       <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
       <exportFonts>
           <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'Calibri'</export>
           <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'Calibri'</export>
       </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>

    <fontFamily name="Century Gothic">
       <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/centurygothic/century-gothic.ttf</normal>
       <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/centurygothic/century-gothic-bold.ttf</bold>
       <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/centurygothic/century-gothic-italic.ttf</italic>
       <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/centurygothic/century-gothic-bold-italic.ttf</boldItalic>
       <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
       <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
       <exportFonts>
           <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'Century Gothic'</export>
           <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'Century Gothic'</export>
       </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>   


</fontFamilies>
```

Note that I just added the last three fonts.

After that I prepared the jar file and put it in my app classpath as mandatory. So far I just got the report exported with normal Sanserif font...

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any ideas?

Thanks!

Quick informative note: I'm using Jaspersoft Studio Community edition (6.3.0) and my app is deployed in a JBoss server.

Comment: Usually the [official documentation](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension) should be preferred over a blog. Sorry to read that you're using JBoss.

Comment: @Lille Debugging (the remote or local) can help to diagnose the problem. You can easy check the font availability during this process. Did you try to write small console application (or test) to check the problem local?

Comment: @Lille Maybe the *ttf* files location is wrong or you are using fonts wrong (report's template problem)

Comment: @DaveJarvis I'm also working with maven, so my question now would be how to put the dependencies of the fonts in the maven's pom.xml?

Comment: @AlexK I did one simple template with four textField and no more than that. If I execute the report in JSS it works fine, even exporting the PDF from there. The problem comes when I put this template in my app (web) and deploy it from there. What I did was, I added the fonts to JSS  (Arial, Calibri and Century Gothic) and exported it later as a jar. Put the jar in my classpath (Java Biuld Path) and put the right dependencies in the pom.xml file...still not working when deploying in my application. What or where else should I look at? BTW how can I debug and find out the font is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found out what was happening in my case and now it's working.

When I introduced the fonts (.ttf extension) in Jaspersoft Studio *Windows->Preferences->Fonts* I selected a wrong value for the PDF Encoding selection combo. I first selected **CP1252 (Western European ANSI aka WinAnsi)** which is **WRONG** if you want to export reports in PDF, then I chose **Identity-H (Unicode with horizontal writing)** instead and it worked fine.

However, what I still don't understand is: if in my report I'm only using Calibri and Century Gothic fonts, why in earth when I go to see the fonts used in my PDF (*File->Properties->Fonts*) I get also Helvetica in the list of fonts used?

Comment: when you select Identity-H as pdf encoding method it gets Helvetica as default font unless you specify pdfFontName property

Answer (score 1):

1. **Export font from jasper report as extension (.jar)** (tool/option/fonts).
2. Add exported font jar to your project.

   https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-fix-problem-custom-fonts-jasperreports-server

Answer (score 1):

By including the below maven dependency in your pom the bold styling will be shown in the generated PDF

```
<dependency>
  <groupid>net.sf.jasperreports</groupid>
  <artifactid>jasperreports-fonts</artifactid>
  <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```